# Nullable decimal to decimal with 3 zero's after

Tags: c#, decimal

How to convert nullable decimal to decimal with 3 zero's after the decimal point.

eg:  cubed  --> decimal?  (data type)-- sql server gives value 5324 for this property. in my viewmodel i have

```
decimal cdb
```

in my databuilder class i am converting this to

```
cbd=cubed??0.
```

thus cbd=5324
but i want

```
cbd=5324.000
```

how can i get this.?

Comment: `ToString("0.000") `?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen - I think the question is more related to the internal workings of `decimal` rather than just being able to call `.ToString(...)`.

Comment: @Enigmativity Since it doesn't really matter in any other place than on presentation layer how many decimal zeroes there are, it isn't clear.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen - I understand what you're saying, but that's what the OP is explicitly asking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I write this code:

```
decimal? cubed = 5324m;
decimal cdb = cubed ?? 0.000m;
Console.WriteLine(cdb);
```

I get `5324` written to the console.

if I change it to this:

```
decimal? cubed = null;
decimal cdb = cubed ?? 0.000m;
Console.WriteLine(cdb);
```

I get `0.000`. Decimals "remember" how many zeros after the decimal point.

I run these two lines:

```
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(":", decimal.GetBits(5324m).Select(x => x.ToString())));
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(":", decimal.GetBits(5324.000m).Select(x => x.ToString())));
```

I get these out:

```
5324:0:0:0
5324000:0:0:196608
```

So to get the value returned with the internal representation of having three zero decimal places you can do this:

```
decimal? cubed = 5324m;
decimal cdb = cubed ?? 0m;
int[] bits = decimal.GetBits(cdb);
cdb = new decimal(new [] { bits[0] * 1000, 0, 0, 196608});
Console.WriteLine(cdb);
```

This gives me:

```
5324.000
```

This code works correctly for values from `0m` to `4294967m`. If you need it to work for values outside of this range some more work on the `bits` values would need to be done.